# After upgrade Netbean to 7.3.1 that change Eclipselink to 2.5 I found this error

Tags: eclipselink

After I upgrade Netbeans to 7.3.1 that come with eclipeLink 2.5 and Glassfish4.
When I ran by application I always got this error message

> SEVERE:   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Cannot call
>   methods requiring a transaction if the entity manager has not been
>   joined to the current transaction.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

JPA requires you to call em.joinTransaction() if a JTA transaction is started after the entityManager was obtained.  Prior to EclipseLink 2.5, EclipseLink might automatically flush to the active transaction even if it wasn't joined to it as described in bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404294